# How to grey scale svg images in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I use react-native-remote-svg package to show my svg images. The problem is I don't know how to greyscale them. I already tried
https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters
but the filter make no changes on svg images.
I also tried https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot to change images to png and then apply the filter, still I was facing issues. The shot some times showed images correctly, and other times I all got was blank.
Note: I am trying to apply greyscale to images, not icons. So I probably can not change it to font either.

Any help would be appreciated.